# ERRO NA QUERY sequelize association LEFT OUTER JOIN API NODEJS

Tags: sql, node.js, api, sequelize-js, inner-join

Tenho a seguinte comando SQL:

```
select u.name_user, a.type_administrator from users u inner join administrators a on u.id_user = a.id_administrator;
```

e preciso transformar isso na minha API em NodeJS
então tenho na model user:

```
    static associate(models) {
    this.hasOne(models.Administrator, {foreignKey: 'id_administrator', as: 'administrator'});
    }
```

na model administrator:

```
static associate(models) {
    this.hasOne(models.User, {foreignKey: 'id_user', as: 'user'})
}
```

e por fim na controller administrator tenho:

```
async indexById(req, res) {
    const { id_user } = req.params;

    const user = await User.findByPk(id_user, {
      include: { association: 'administrator'}
    });

    return res.json(user.administrator);
},
```

o problema é que o resultado disso é:

```
SELECT "User"."id_user", "User"."name_user", "administrator"."id_administrator" "administrator"."type_administrator" FROM "users" AS "User" LEFT OUTER JOIN "administrators" AS "administrator" ON "User"."id_user" = "administrator"."id_administrator" WHERE "User"."id_user" = '1';
```

como puderam observar gera uma query com LEFT OUTER JOIN isso faz com que não liste o user juntamente com o administrator e eu preciso que gere um INNER JOIN pra dessa forma aparecer a informação completa. Alguém sabe como consertar?

lembrando que o id_administrator e id_user são os mesmos [PFK]

Answer (score 0):

Veja se funciona assim:

```
  async indexById(req, res) {
    const { id_user } = req.params;

    const user = await User.findByPk(id_user, {
      include: { association: 'administrator',required: true}
    });

    return res.json(user.administrator);
},
```